# How can I use a string input from an R function to name a dataset?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, function, input

I want to create a very simple function that takes part of a large dataset (df) and creates a new dataset in the global environment with a specified name. The problem is that it seems to name the new dataframe "x" instead of the actual string input. Example:

```
create_dataset<-function(x,rows,columns) {
  name<<-df[rows,columns]
}

create_dataset(x="skildpadde",
               rows=690:692,
               columns=2:7)
```

How can I use the input "x" as the dataset name?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you are doing this.. Is your source dataset `df`, or is your source dataset `skildapple`?  If the source is `df`, are you trying to create an object in the global environment called `skildapple`? If the latter, why do you need a function?

Comment: Perhaps i didnt formulate the question very clearly. The source dataset is df and an example name is "skildpadde" of a new dataframe im trying to name in the global environment. The reason i need a function is because i need to do this many times to extract different parts of the source dataset. The problem has been solved however :)

Comment: You can use `.GlobalEnv[[x]] <- df[rows,columns]` in the function

Comment: It's a really bad idea to create a function like this. R users don't expect a function to write anything into their global environment unless they ask for the output to be stored. Why would you want to use the syntax `create_dataset("skildapple", 1, 2)` when you could instead do `skildapple <- create_dataset(1, 2)`, which gives the user more freedom and is much more idiomatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get()`:

```
create_dataset<-function(x,rows,columns) {
  get(x)[rows,columns]
}
```

Or, if you trying to assign to `x` in the global environment:

```
create_dataset<-function(x,rows,columns) {
  assign(x, df[rows,columns],envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

I'm not sure I understand the use case or rationale behind either of these...

Comment: maybe you are trying to assign to the global environment? See my second option

Comment: Thank you very much! I need to do this a bunch of times to extract data from the large dataset and assign it in the global environment :) I really appreciate the help!

Comment: looks like a named subset...